# how to get the word between two character in vim script?

Tags: vim, neovim

My cursor is on the word `<header>`.

If I run the function `expand("<cword>")` it will return for me the word `<header>` I want get only what is between `<>` which is `header`.

I want to write a function that takes three arguments

```
foo(string, startChar, endChar)
```

and returns the characters between `startChar` and `endChar`.

Could you help please ?

Comment: The easiest way to get `header` out of `<header>` is `yi<` (yank inside angle brackets: `:help yank`, `:help text-objects`, `:help i<`). Do you actually need a function, or is this enough?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `expand("<cword>")` already returns `header` out of the box, so the question should be "why does it return `<header>`?", not "how to get `header`?".

Comment: Sorry I just mixed between <cWORD> and "<cword>" but my purpose was to find a way to take a word between start and end characters. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching an answer I found one.
The answer is that by default the `expand('<cword>')` return the word between special character such as '<' or '' ...
but if I want to get the groups of characters between two indexes we can write a function that do the job

```
function Get_string_between(string, start, end)
  let str=""
  "get length of string
  let len =strlen(a:string)

  "set the default values o start and end indexes to 0
  let startIndex=0
  let endIndex=0


"Get the index of start and end characters
  let i =0
  while i < len
    if a:string[i]  == a:start && startIndex == 0
      let startIndex =i
    elseif a:string[i] == a:end && endIndex == 0
      let endIndex =i
    endif
    let i += 1
  endwhile
  echo "StartIndex: ". startIndex
  echo "endIndex: ". endIndex

  let i =startIndex+1

  while i < endIndex
    let str .= a:string[i]
    let i +=1
  endwhile
  return str
endfunction
```